# how to move website from WAMP to LAMP server

Tags: php, lamp, wampserver

i built my site on WAMP and now need to move everything over to LAMP. I understand that include paths are different in LAMP. What do I need to do for the site to work without having to change my code?

```
phpinfo();
include_path

.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
```

is there anything else to look out for when moving a website from WAMP to LAMP?

Comment: Pretty sure you can just copy and paste (and copy the database data over) unless you have files that are outside of the wwwroot folder (Such as database connection includes)

Comment: And check how your files reference each other (e.g. no absolute paths, use forward slash `/` for separation, etc.

Comment: It didnt work like that. The only things that loaded in LAMP was the html. I had to change paths from WAMP:/includes/footer.php to LAMP:./inlcudes/footer.php but I can't go back to every page and change that. I also don't get any php errors and not sure how to turn them on

Comment: If you use specific libraries you need to make sure that the new server supports these too.

Comment: Compare your phpinfo() from WAMP and LAMP

Comment: Unless you used absolute paths in your source, it should translate over seamlessly. @Dev-Ria There is a difference between ./ and ../ - the former specifies the current directory, while the latter specifies the parent directory...this is universal across windows and linux, so you must've changed your directory structure in copying documents over.

Comment: @crush is right; PHP accepts forward slash `/` as a directory separator regardless of platform. Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `__DIR__` to help you avoid needing to specify any absolute paths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Porting from WAMP to LAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143334/porting-from-wamp-to-lamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue I have when porting sites from Windows to Linux is **filenames and paths**. See, Linux is case-sensitive, while Windows is not.

To help you debug those and other errors, you can turn PHP errors on, by searching for and changing two settings in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

You can also read the error log in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` instead of displaying all the errors.

Also, in future I suggest that you **develop on the platform you are going to deploy to**.

Comment: Exactly why developers should follow *nix naming conventions on Windows. If it works on *nix, it will work on Windows, but not vice-versa.

Comment: why is it that header('Refresh:2; URL=index.php'); works perfectly in WAMP but I get the error that header was already sent in header.php in LAMP?

Comment: You can't add any more header lines using the header() function once the header block has already been sent. Take a look at [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). I would also compare phpinfo() output to make sure you have the same server settings on both machines.